# Is there any way to implement functionality similar to wpf expander using c++ and wxwidget

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, expander

I want to implement a GUI and I like to hide part of screen when it is not needed, similar to the expander (http://wpftutorial.net/Expander.html) in wpf.

I am using wxwidget.

Answer (score 3):

I think [`wxCollapsiblePane`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0.2/classwx_collapsible_pane.html) is the equivalent control in wxWidgets.